# PC won't recognize Philips TV

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, tv, edid

When I connect my Windows 10(latest enterprise build) to my old Philips 42PFL3604H/12 the PC/TV via HDMI just won't connect. That's it. The TV won't appear on device manager nor on Nvidia's control Panel

Tech info:
- Self-built PC with GeForce 1060 graphics card
- Old "smart" TV Philips 42PFL3604H/12 with latest firmware(2012) installed

What have I tried:
- Using another HDMI port on TV and on graphics card
- Using another cable
- Restarting TV
- Restarting PC
- Restarting TV to factory defaults
- Disabling transient Multimon Manager (TMM) on Windows Registry

Interesting data:
I have a Xbox 360 which is connected via HDMI to the same TV. However, the Xbox showed strange behavior, like, audio not working and Xbox heavily lagging. To fix this, I disabled EDID on my Xbox settings and I manually set up the screen resolution and other settings

Comment: Have you tried a different cable? Do you have any other hdmi devices besides your Xbox that show odd behavior?

Comment: Different Cable does not work. Only device I've tested so far is a W10 laptop which doesn't work either.
I'll try my raspberry later